# How to remove weird glitching effect in viewport

Tags: modeling

I've been working on a game modelling a rail. I've came to a problem with my viewport. [image] How do i remove this weird glitching effect?

Comment: Maybe you have overlapping geom or something around that. This is not a viewport issue.

Comment: I have only one cube there. I don't know what would be overlapping, how do i fix it?

Comment: Could you upload your file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? So that we can try to understand what is happening?

Comment: Ok for press n go to view and set the min clip distance to .1 or larger